# Engine chugging while idle, misfires when accelerating and loss of power

Tags: misfire, peugeot

When I was driving my Peugeot 407 petrol I suddenly experienced a loss of power. Luckily I was close to home and was able to drive the few meters back. When I started the car again the engine was chugging and shaking while idle. And when stepping on the gas pedal some random misfires would occur. I only have a cheap OBDII. It shows error P1340 and P1336, but ONLY after a misfire takes place.

I tried changing the spark plugs, but not difference yet. I have also tried to look under the hood to see any differences or visable problems, but the only thing I see is the engine moving more that usual when idle.

Anyone got an idea what could be wrong, and can point me in the right direction? I have had a depolution system faulty error come and go for a while, but I'm not sure if it's related.

Answer (score 1):

Some possible causes for these codes are:

- P1340: Camshaft position sensor
- P1336: Ignition coil

You changed the spark plugs which is probably a good first step.  Some other possibilities are a tank of bad fuel, a clogged fuel filter, clogged fuel injector, dirty air filter, weak fuel pump, bad ignition coil.

I like to start with the simplest and cheapest options first.  So a good plan to check would be:

1. Air filter
2. Ignition coil (swap them around and see if the problem follows
3. Fuel filter
4. Fuel pump (rent a fuel pressure gauge from a local auto parts store)
5. Run a can of fuel injector cleaner through the system.

The camshaft position sensor may be an easy fix.  It's worth checking the wires/connectors too.

Comment: Yeah, I found the causes for the error codes, but since they only display after the first misfire, I don't think they show the full picture. The chugging and shaking starts immediately when I start the engine. Thanks for giving me some directions to go. What would you say is the easiest/best/cheapest place to start? Replacing fuel pump and ignition coil would probably be the last to try I guess? The fuel is from the same gas station as usual, so I think it would be unlikely.